# Prove that $x=4-\frac{x+\sin{x}}{3}$ has only one solution in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

[image]

Prove that it has exactly one solution for $f(x) = x$.

My try:

$$x = 4-\frac{x+\sin{x}}{3}\iff-12+4x=\sin{x}$$

However I do not know how to continue

Comment: You should have $-\sin x$ in your final step, right?

Comment: $x$ is between $11/4=2.75>\pi/2$ and $13/4=3.25<3\pi/2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the equation $-12+4x=\sin(x)$ had two distinct solutions $a$ and $b$, then$$-12+4a=\sin(a)\quad\text{and}\quad-12+4b=\sin(b),$$and therefore $4(a-b)=\sin(a)-\sin(b)$. But, by the Mean Value Theorem,$$\sin(a)-\sin(b)=(a-b)\cos(c)$$for some $c$ between $a$ and $b$. And$$4(a-b)=(a-b)\cos(c)\implies\cos(c)=4,$$which is impossible.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

From your last step, we need to fix the sign for $\sin x$, then let consider

$$f(x)=-12+4x+\sin x \implies f'(x) =4+\cos x>0$$

Comment: I see, so because it's strictly increasing there is going to be only one intersection at $f(x) = 0$ right?

Comment: @VLC You need to show there is a solution first.

Comment: Yes that's the idea since the function is continuous and we can invoke IVT (intermediate value theorem), therefore at least a solution exists and since it is strictly increasing we only have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x) = 4 - \frac{x+ \sin x}{3}$ has derivative
$f'(x) = -\frac{1 + \cos x}{3}$, so $-\frac{2}{3} \le f'(x)\le 0$, and therefore $|f'(x)|\le \frac{2}{3} < 1$. We conclude
$$|f(x_1) - f(x_2)| \le \frac{2}{3} |x_1- x_2|$$
so $f$ is a contraction, and as such, has a unique [fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem).